# Render GEO cities on chart using highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to Render GEO cities on chart using highchart javascript library. Is it possible with highgchart. By using google chating library it is possible but I need to implement chart using highchart.

I found it is possible using google charts:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap

but need to do same using highchart. Any idea?

Thx

Comment: Crazy, geocities is still around? Oh, only in Japan. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoCities

Comment: Something like this? http://www.highcharts.com/studies/map-from-svg.htm#World1

Comment: @John Klakegg  Thanks to aware me about possibility by using highchart. Actually I have to render geo_city database field data. I have another database column geo_country. In this way, I have country and city but still I am not getting how I can render cities belonging to different countries using highchart. Do you know any highchart based code for mapping which give me some startup?